# HAProxy reqirep setting results in 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: haproxy, regex

I am trying to rewrite a single path via HAProxy. Without the rule in place, a 404 is returned for the directory page (from an IIS node). Once I add the rule, the page returns a 504 Gateway Timeout after a minute or so.

```
backend Example_Backend
    balance uri
    reqirep ^([^\ ]*)\ (.*)/directory/?[\ ]    \1\ \2/target.asp\ 
    server Server1 x.x.x.xx4:80 weight 25 check fall 10 rise 2 maxconn 40
    server Server2 x.x.x.xx5:80 weight 25 check fall 10 rise 2 maxconn 40
    server Server3 x.x.x.xx6:80 weight 25 check fall 10 rise 2 maxconn 40
    server Server4 x.x.x.xx7:80 weight 25 check fall 10 rise 2 maxconn 40
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I'm using reqirep? I have tested using `sed` to make sure it matches correctly for the following:

```
GET http://www.example.com/directory HTTP/1.1
GET http://www.example.com/directory/ HTTP/1.1
```

Thoughts?

Edit: Logs from testing /directory and /directory/

```
haproxy[25957]: x.x.x.100:50941 [31/May/2011:14:53:24.836] Example_Frontend Example_Backend/Server4 77/0/3/-1/50083 504 194 - - sH-- 1/1/1/1/0 0/0 "GET /directory/ HTTP/1.1"
haproxy[25957]: x.x.x.100:50942 [31/May/2011:14:53:26.124] Example_Frontend Example_Backend/Server4 78/0/5/-1/50087 504 194 - - sH-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /directory HTTP/1.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyril from the HAProxy mailing list pointed out that the regex was removing the HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/1.0 from the request. He suggested the following (which worked):

```
reqirep ^([^\ ]*)\ (.*)/directory/?\ (.*)       \1\ \2/target.asp\ \3
```